# Runtime error after compilation on LeetCode

Tags: c++

> Line 859: Char 45: runtime error: applying non-zero offset
> 18446744073709551612 to null pointer (stl_iterator.h) SUMMARY:
> UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior
> /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_iterator.h:868:45

I am getting this error after compilation of my code on LeetCode, on "(121.) Best Time to Buy and Sell Stock" problem.

My code is:

```
class Solution {
   public:
   int maxProfit(vector<int>& prices)
   {
        vector<int> profit;
        int buy,num;
        for(int i=0; i<prices.size()-1; i++)
        {
            buy=prices[i];
            for(int j=i+1; j<prices.size(); j++)
            {
                if(buy < prices[j])
                   profit.push_back(prices[j]-buy);
            }
            
        }
        vector<int>::iterator it = profit.end()-1;
        if(!profit.empty())
        {
          sort(profit.begin(), profit.end());
          num = *(profit.end()-1);
          return num ;
        }
        else
          return 0;
    }
};
```

Comment: Probably happens when `prices` is empty, then `prices.size()-1` will underflow and become a huge number.

Comment: yes but after   `vector<int>::iterator it = profit.end()-1; ` removing this statement it is also showing ,can you explain sir.

Comment: If you don't need this line, don't show it to the world.

Comment: Change your for loop to `for(int i=0; i<prices.size(); i++)`

Answer (score 2):

std::vector::size is a [method that returns](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size) a ***size_t*** size.

What you need to know is that ***size_t*** [is unsigned](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t). This means that if a vector is empty, `prices.size()-1` will be a gigantic value, given that this operation will be treated as unsigned and thus cannot represent a negative value. If you, for example, ask the compiler to treat this operation as int, by casting, for example, the problem should be gone.

`for(int i=0; i < static_cast<int>(prices.size()-1); i++)`

Back to your problem, since you allow the first loop iteration to happen, the expression `buy=prices[i]` will be evaluated for i = 0. Therefore, you are trying to access an invalid memory area and the sanitizer will complain and finish the program.